# PLACEHOLDER - Vim-Exchange Plugin for Vim

Tags: app, placeholder

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Will update with screenshots after testing.

### About

Tell us about your app.
Why did you create it? Who is it for?
I used a few other plugins for searching SO questions within Vim before, but none really that fit my needs. I want to be able to search, and filter questions, and look at my favorites all within Vim. That's the main goal for this Vim plugin.

How does it work? What problem does it solve?
It will work by giving commands, i.e. `:StackExchange queryString` this would open up a new buffer where user can look at questions. In addition user can save/unsave as favorite. The other useful command would be `:StackFavorites queryString`

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

This vim plugin will be able to be installed just like any other vim plugin, and further instructions will be on this link https://github.com/kodaman2/vim-stackexchange

#### Platform

Any platform that supports python, and vim.

### Contact

Who created this app? Who are the key contributors?
How do we get in touch with them or find them?
Creator: Fernando Balandran fredz0003@gmail.com
https://github.com/kodaman2/vim-stackexchange

### Code

Plugin mainly written in python and interfacing with VimL.